# Does SonarQube give different errors for same code base

Tags: sonarqube, sonar-runner, sonarqube-scan

WE are facing an issue while trying to run sonar analysis.we have two different project with same code base,quality profiles,pugins,version and exclusions but sonar is failing for critical issues error on one of the project but not the other.can anyone help me?

Comment: also plugin-versions?

Comment: generally i would advice you to post your SonarQube version, which plugins, in which version, and what rule is eg. not showing up. Additionally to that, the project configuration of both projects, and what analysis you are doing, are you doing both times a full analysis or are you doing previews?

Comment: SonarQube Version-5.6

Comment: SonarQube Version-5.6 ,                                                                      QUALITY-PROFILES :(C)Sonar way,(Objective-C)Mobile way,(Swift)Mobile waY    .MOBILE-QUALITY-GATE:CONDITIONS   -Only project measures are checked against thresholds. Sub-projects, directories and files are ignored.
Project health icons represent:
 at least one threshold is defined, no threshold is reached.
 at least one warning threshold is reached, no error threshold is reached.
 at least one error threshold is reached.sonar scanner-2.8 and build wrapper-3.6